# how to trigger reload browser tab

Tags: php, javascript, html, debugging

How to trigger browser to reload/refresh page ?

I'm using php, and wrote a class for debug. The debug class will output my log to a file. 
The file log will always be recreated each time debug executed.

Supposed that the file log is html, and I view it with my browser.
I don't know how to refresh the page each time the log file is recreated.

Browser is Firefox or Chrome. 
Any idea ?

Note : 
I know this can be done via interval continous check using ajax in the page. Is there any api provided by FF or Chrome to just refresh specific tab page when NEEDED ?

Comment: Does the log refresh at intervals? If so, you could use a PHP redirect script that redirects it to the same page. `header( "refresh:[seconds];url=http://yourwebsite.com/page.php" );
 
}`

Comment: you want to refresh that tab containing your log file every time it is modified by another http request ? add some js to your log file with a setinterval and an ajax request that check for last modified date

Comment: Try to reload the page using ajax ?

Comment: yes I know this can be done with continuous interval check using ajax. But I mean is there any api provided by browser to just reload the page when needed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox add-on "Auto-reload". 
It can specify which *file* to monitor when executing some *url*.

Answer (score 0):

While it might not do *exactly* what you want [livejs](http://livejs.com/) almost fits the bill. It looks for changes in the headers and will reload the page if the last-changed date has changed since last check.

Usage is fairly simple, place the script somewhere accessible and put

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/livejs.js'></script>
```

in your `head`

Comment: Really thanks for pointing out livejs. I tested and kind of love it. But then I found FF add-on "Auto-reload". It can set local files to monitor and refresh will triggered if those files were modified.